Why doesn't the highlighted date in Fluent UI React's DatePicker change if default value was set?
Referring to Fluent UI React v9's DatePicker: https://react.fluentui.dev/?path=/docs/compat-components-datepicker--default, the value property is the default value. But when I set it, something strange happens.
Whenever I set the value property, the highlighted Day in the DatePicker stays the same regardless of selecting any date in the DatePicker.
How do I ensure the highlighted day gets changed accordingly when default value has been set? My thinking of applying useState and rerender the DatePicker but that would be overkill I feel.

NOTE: If I just set the initialDatePicker value, the highlighted Day changes based on selected date but the text input field will not display the initial date
Also, this is what I mean by highlighted Day

Here's the code & demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ppi3bg?file=src%2Fexample.tsx

The issue you're encountering is because when you set the value prop to a specific date, the DatePicker component doesn't automatically update the highlighted day to match that date. This is by design behavior in Fluent UI React DatePicker.
To ensure that the highlighted day changes accordingly when the default value is set, you can handle it programmatically by updating the initialPickerDate to match the value date. Here's how you can do it:
import * as React from 'react';
import { DatePicker } from '@fluentui/react-datepicker-compat';
import { Field } from '@fluentui/react-components';
import type { DatePickerProps } from '@fluentui/react-datepicker-compat';

export const Default = (props: Partial<DatePickerProps>) => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(new Date());
  const initialPickerDate = props.initialPickerDate || selectedDate;
  const handleDateChange = (date: Date | null | undefined) => {
    if (date) {
      setSelectedDate(date);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Field label="Select a date (Input field has value but highlight wouldn't change)">
        <DatePicker
          placeholder="Select a date..."
          value={selectedDate}
          initialPickerDate={initialPickerDate}
          onSelectDate={handleDateChange}
          {...props}
        />
      </Field>
      <Field label="Select a date #2 (highlight changes but no initial value in Input field)">
        <DatePicker
          placeholder="Select a date..."
          initialPickerDate={new Date('May 2, 2024')}
          {...props}
        />
      </Field>
    </>
  );
};

I maintain a state called selectedDate to keep track of the date I select. I use this selectedDate as both the value prop for the DatePicker and the default value for initialPickerDate. Additionally, I provide a function called handleDateChange to update the selectedDate whenever I change the date in the DatePicker. This ensures that the highlighted day changes accordingly to the date I select.
